# SwiftUI TabView more tab content not showing

Tags: swiftui, tabview

I am working on a SwiftUI app that uses TabView as the main navigation. I currently have six items, each of which reference another View for content display:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    init() {
        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.black
        UITabBar.appearance().isOpaque = true
    }

    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ToDoListView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "checkmark.rectangle.fill")
                    Text("To Do List")
            }


            ProjectView()
                .tabItem {

                    Image(systemName: "archivebox.fill")
                    Text("Projects")
            }

            SavedListView()
                .tabItem {

                    Image(systemName: "list.bullet")
                    Text("Saved Lists")
            }

            NewsletterView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "doc.text")
                    Text("Newsletter")
            }

            AboutView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "person.2.fill")
                    Text("About")
            }

            FeedBackView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "text.bubble")
                    Text("Feedback")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Content for the first four items displays fine, but when I tap on the **More** button, content for the last two items does not display when tapped.

If I move the last two items forward to positions 1-4 they work as expected. Is there something about TabView that I am missing?

Comment: Could you find a solution yet?